# Create multiple threads and wait for them all to complete, calling again for the complete

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Web Service, to make the load of the database server for a local database, making 100 requests for records.

Since the process is slow, I want to create ten threads, not to use too much memory, making Web Service calls, and when one of the threads, finished, over 100 call records. How do part of the thread?

Example:

Create thread 1
Create thread 2
Create thread 3
Create thread 4

thread 1 complete change Web Service again

#### Edit

My code not working. Variable `send`always gets the value 10 and not 0,1,2,3,4 and etc.

```
Int32 page = 0;            
do
{                
    for (int iterator=0; iterator < 10; iterator++)
    {                    
        listTask[iterator] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Int32 send = iterator + page * 10;
            DoStatus("Page: " + send.ToString());
            Processamento(parametros, filial, send);                        
        });
    }

    Task.WaitAll(listTask);
    page++;

}
while (true); // Test only
```

Comment: You could use round robin to cycle through your threads. Or you keep your threads in an array an check for each item which is unused.

Comment: @user743414 have an example? tks

Comment: Have you looked at `Task.WhenAny()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you know how much records you will get, or do you want to stop when all is loaded ?

Comment: @BenRobinson Be careful, it's only Framework 4.5 ;)

Comment: @mtsys which version of Framework do you use ?

Comment: @Xaruth I know when it will stop, when the amount of return is less than 100, it indicates that no more records because the research is paged

Comment: Seems to me your real question is: this is slow, how do I make it faster? Answer: use an array and send more than one record per call to the service. In the service, open the connection to the database, insert all records in the array, then close the connection. The effect of doing this will be much higher than using threads.

Comment: @mtsys For you edit error, put `Int32 send = iterator + page * 10;` out the Task. See my answer (I corrected it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing over the loop variable.  You need to remember that lambdas close over *variables* not over *values*.  Your tasks will each read the value of `iterator` *at the time that the lambda executes* `iterator + page * 10`.  By the time that that happens the main thread has already incremented it to `10`.

This is simple enough to resolve.  Make a copy of the loop variable inside of your `for` loop so that the closure closes over *that* variable, which never changes.

```
for (int iterator=0; iterator < 10; iterator++)
{
    int i = iterator;
    listTask[iterator] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Int32 send = i + page * 10;
        DoStatus("Page: " + send.ToString());
        Processamento(parametros, filial, send);                        
    });
}
```

Comment: i'm surprising that some can upvote for a answer wich is a copy-paste of another answer posted 12 minutes earlier.

Comment: @Xaruth It's not a copy paste.  There are several differences.  Your answer doesn't explain the actual problem at all, it just fixes it along with making a large number of other changes, making it extremely difficult to determine what the actual problem was and how it was fixed.  I didn't so much as even read your answer, given that glancing at it makes it clear that that I'd need to invest a huge amount of time just to see what you changed.

Comment: you answered the second question, wich was an edit. I answer the original question, then a modify my answer with the second question (wich is from my answer). I think there's something wrong in StackOverflow ... Sorry, I prefer not to continue here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to create 10 threads, wait for all, then recreate 10 threads, etc. Each thread load 100 results.

In this answer, results are `String` but that can be changed.

```
private void Load()
{
    Boolean loading = true;
    List<String> listResult = new List<String>();
    Int32 boucle = 0;

    Task[] listTask = new Task[10];

    do
    {
        // create 10 threads (=1000 results)
        for (int iterator=0; iterator < 10; iterator++)
        {
            // [0-99] [100-199] [200-299] ...
            Int32 start = 100 * iterator + 1000 * boucle;
            Int32 end = start + 99;

            listTask[iterator] = Task<List<String>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                List<String> data = LoadData(start, end);
                return data;
            });
        }

        // wait for 10 threads to finish
        Task.WaitAll(listTask);

        // collapse results
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            listResult.AddRange((listTask[i] as Task<List<String>>).Result);
        }

        // check if there is 100 results in last thread
        loading = (listTask[9] as Task<List<String>>).Result.Count == 100;

        // ready for another iteration (next 1000 results)
        boucle++;
    }
    while (loading);
}

private List<string> LoadData(int p1, int p2)
{
    // TODO : load data from p1 to p2
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```